# fetch the associative array particular value with its key name

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i have a function . here i am passing an array applicationTabId = {"twitter": "15", "dropbox": "14"}; "}; I have an ajax success function .In this the variable appName name holds the key names as twitter , dropbox etc. I got this from database as ajax response. i want to find the value associated with this from the array. variable appName holding the key names and iam getting it from database as ajax response. i need to check the corresponding value of this name from array.

```
function getapplicationlogouturl(applicationTabId) {


     chrome.storage.sync.get("endpoint", function (obj) {
        FetchLogoutUrl =  {
            "applicationName": applicationTabId,
            "sdcode": sdcode,
            "type": "Chrome Fetch Application Logout Url"
        };
        $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
            url:      obj.endpoint,
            dataType: "json",
            data:    JSON.stringify(FetchLogoutUrl),
            context: document.body,
            timeout: globalTimeout,
                success: function (response) {

                if (response != null ) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var appName = response[i].name;
                        console.log(applicationTabId);
// o/p as {"twitter": "15", "dropbox": "14"}
                        console.log(appName);
//o/p as twitter
//dropbox

                      var tabid = applicationTabId.appName;
                      //var tabid = applicationTabId[appName];
                      console.log(tabid);
   //o/p as undefined
                      console.log(appName+'---'+tabid);


                        if (appName in applicationTabId){

                        }
                   }        
                }
            },

        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: {"twitter": "15", "dropbox": "14"} is Object. use like `var tabid = applicationTabId[appName];`

Comment: i have modified my actual requirement in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply loop like below:

```
$.each(applicationTabId, function(key,value){
   console.log(key);
   console.log(value);
});
```

Based on code you provided now, change your code like below:

```
function getapplicationlogouturl(applicationTabId) {
    FetchLogoutUrl =  {
        "applicationName": applicationTabId,
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: obj.endpoint,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(FetchLogoutUrl),
        context: document.body,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null ) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    var appName = response[i].name;
                    var tabid = applicationTabId[appName];
                    //print key value data in console to check working fine
                    console.log(appName+'---'+tabid);
                }
            }
        },
    });
}
```

***Note:-*** `var appName` and `var tabid` value will be changed after each iteration happen.

Comment: Thank you for you support. it was the pblm with json signify. i was getting key valye as "twitter" "11", had an extra quote in the appName applicationTabId[appName];
Thank youu

Comment: actually I had the same issue, thanks for the answer @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie ;)

Comment: @DeepKakkar  glad to help you  buddy :):)

Comment: @user2830078  glad to help you :):). Happy coding